# web audio, createMediaElementSource variable sources

Tags: javascript, html, audio, web-audio-api

lets say i wan't to have an app that has variable audio sources as audio tags like so:

```
<audio preload="auto" src="1.mp3" controls="" class="muzz"></audio>
<audio preload="auto" src="track.mp3" controls="" class="muzz"></audio>
```

Depending on which of them is played it should be passed to createMediaElementSource and then the sound would be sent to analyser and various things would be done with it, but it doesn't work:

```
var trackName;
//get the source of clicked track
$(".muzz").on("play", function(){
    trackName = $(this).attr("src");
    console.log("got a source: ", trackName);
    audio = new Audio();
    audio.src=trackName;




    context = new AudioContext();
    analyser = context.createAnalyser();
    source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
    source.connect(analyser);
    analyser.connect(context.destination); 

    letsDraw();


});
```

the console log displays the correct source name, the letsDraw() method is supposed to draw a spectrogram of the audio playing:

```
function letsDraw(){
console.log("draw called");
window.requestAnimationFrame(letsDraw);
fbc_array = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
analyser.getByteFrequencyData(fbc_array); //get frequency from the analyser node
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

ctx.fillStyle="white";
ctx.font = "bold 12px Arial";
ctx.fillText("currently playing:" + trackName, 10, 20);//this works

bars =  150;
for(var i = 0; i < analyser.frequencyBinCount; i++){ //but this doesn't


    /*fill the canvas*/
    x = i *2;
    barWidth = 1;
    barHeight = -(fbc_array[i]/1.8); 

    //colours react to the  frequency loudness
        hue = parseInt(500 * (1 - (barHeight / 200)), 10); 
            ctx.fillStyle = 'hsl(' + hue + ',75%,50%)';

    ctx.fillRect(x, canvas.height, barWidth, barHeight);

}

}
```

it was working fine with one set audio source, but fails with variable sources, any ideas would be very appreciated.

of course, no errors are even thrown in the console at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I don't get is why you take the src and put that in a new Audio object, as you already have them.

It is also way better to create a source from both `<audio>` tags. You just create a function that runs on page load (so when everything on the page is ready so you won't get any errors about elements not yet existing etc.).

Before I start writing a piece of code, what do you expect to happen? Should it be possible to have both  tags playing at the same time, or should one be stopped if you click play on the other? If it shouldn't play at the same time, you'd better make one `<audio>` tag and create two buttons which each set the src of the tag.

Another problem with your code is that you already have the `<audio>` elements, and when you want them to play you just create a new audio element and append the src to it.. What is the logic behind that?

EDIT:

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/MarijnS95/Fumxa/) of using multiple sources with only one `<audio>` element.

The HTML code should look like this:

```
<audio id="player" src="" autoplay="" controls=""></audio>
<div id="buttons">
    <!--The javascript code will generate buttons with which you can play the audio-->
</div>
```

Then you use this JS code:

```
onload = function () { //this will be executed when the page is ready
    window.audioFiles = ['track1.mp3', 'track2.mp3']; //this is gonna be the array with all file names
    window.player = document.getElementById('player');
    window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
    context = new AudioContext();
    source = context.createMediaElementSource(player);
    analyser = context.createAnalyser();
    source.connect(analyser);
    analyser.connect(context.destination);

    //now we take all the files and create a button for every file
    for (var x in audioFiles) {
        var btn = document.createElement('button');
        btn.innerHTML = audioFiles[x];
        btn.onclick = function () {
            player.src = audioFiles[x];
            //so when the user clicks the button, the new source gets appended to the audio element
        }
        document.getElementById('buttons').appendChild(btn);
    }

}
```

Hope the comments explain it good enough

EDIT2:

You want to know how to do this for multiple elements. What you want to do is to create all the audio elements when the page loads, and create all sources for it. This will decrease mess when starting to play audio. The code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MarijnS95/Fumxa/2/).

All you need to do is have the for loop that runs for every media file you have, which it will create an audio element for with the appropriate source, and then create a sourcenode for that (`createMediaElementSource`), and connect that sourcenode to the analyser.

I also want to say something about your visualiser code though. If you do not override the font, color or anything, you don't need to execute that every animationframe. Once on init is enough.

Comment: the part about playing them both is taken care of, the one that was playing is stopped in case another audio is played. the problem is, the number, or the source of the audio is not static, it will vary, so there is no way for me to know exactly how many mediaelements to create

Comment: @user2209644 so it looks easier to use one audio element, and dynamically change the src. Else when having a lot of media files with audio elements and sources, I don't know how negative that will effect performance.

Comment: i feel really stupid, but i don't follow you, could you please show an example code

Comment: What I mean is that you could better generate a button for every media file, and then have one audio element and one media source object. As the audio elements are not supposed to be playing at the same time, it is easy to append a new source to the element (like click a button and then it will play the file assigned to that button). If you need more info I will write some code here

Comment: Is it possible to have the audio controls for every audio?

Comment: @user2209644 You only have the audio controls for **one** audio element, as you only have **one** audio element. When the user clicks button one for example, we say player.src = 'track1.mp3'. As the element has `autoplay` enabled it will automatically start after loading the source. Of course the previous music stops (pretty logical, as you change the source, so it will not play from the old source anymore).

Comment: yes, that is understandable, but can you make it work with multiple audio elements?

Comment: It can, but why would you want multiple audio elements? As you say they only play one at a time so it will only result in a (huge) performance decrease. Think of having 20 audio elements, all with a different source. Your webbrowser will then load all 20 sources simultaneously. But if you still want to do it with multiple audio elements, I will add some code for that.

Comment: I must say I really like your visualiser. That colors look awesome, good job! As your comment says that it is not working, check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/MarijnS95/Fumxa/6/embedded/result/). _(I do not own these songs, I just hosted them on dropbox for testing purposes)_

Comment: My pleasure! Have you already found out how I fixed your visualiser code?

Answer (score 3):

At the top of your first code block, try this:

```
var trackName,
  context = new AudioContext();
```

And remove `context = new AudioContext();` from the click handler.

You should only have one AudioContext for the page.

Comment: thanks! this seemed to have worked, but now when i try to play anything that was already played (play track, pause, play same again) i get this : Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'createMediaElementSource' on 'AudioContext': invalid HTMLMediaElement.

Comment: @user2209644 the reason you get `invalid HTMLMediaElement` is because you already created a `MediaElementSource` from it. You can't do that twice. Why don't you just call `createMediaElementSource` on page load for both `<audio>` tags?